# md-select same object in ng-option and ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, md-select

Is it possible to use same json object in ng-option and ng-model of md-select?

> Here I'm using Angular Material md-select instead of HTML Select

**Controller:**

```
$scope.languages = [
     { name: 'English', value: true }, 
     { name: 'English', value: false }
];
```

**View:**

```
<md-select ng-model="languages"
             placeholder="Select"
             class="select-dropdown md-no-underline"
             multiple>
    <md-option ng-value="language.value" ng-repeat="language in languages">
      {{language.name}}
    </md-option>

</md-select>
```

Comment: is there some error showing up in your console?

Comment: no. The elements in the dropdown are not working fine.  when i click on checkbox it adds another item in list and the its not unchecked.

Comment: it adds another item? What is meant by this? s some unknown element inserted when you select the optionf from the dropdown

Comment: yes. empty strings appears with checkbox..

Comment: i have tried this before. not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so because when you `select` or `un-select` the list items from your `md-checkbox` it alters the list from which `ng-repeat` is getting values. You need to maintain the selections in another variable.

Comment: I know about this. is there any work around? i want to use the same variable.

Comment: I am afriad, there is no work around for this, you have to use different variable names for the ng-model and the laguages array. BTW why do you want to use the same variable name?

Comment: @Sakky this should be listed as a comment not an answer. To make this an answer, you should add some code supporting your solution. Please edit it, and add some code, and show the user how he can rectify the problem.